# Amadeus Hotel Booking API giving 500 server error?

Tags: amadeus

Hi there i am trying to test the Hotel API For booking but its not working.
[image: Screenshot of the errror]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the 3rd endpoint of the Hotel API in our test environment.

The test environment only has a limited set of data to allow you to try the APIs and prototype with them.

This endpoint (which takes a hotelId (HIPARC12 in your example) and an offerId (E5F6...) as parameters) is not used for booking. This endpoint is used to do an availability and price confirmation. After selecting your hotel and your room, you want to make sure that this room is still available and want to confirm the price.

Regarding the error it's because we are providing a limited set of data in the test environment: all the offers are not available (they are in production).

As of today, we only provide search APIs for Hotel, we don't offer booking capabilities.